# How to join two tables using a sliding window based on dates in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, window, date-range

I have two spark dataframes .

One is a unique ID with their entry date dataframe called entry_table

| ID | entry_date |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 |
| A2 | 2022-02-14 |
| A5 | 2022-02-15 |
| B1 | 2022-02-15 |
| C1 | 2022-02-16 |
| B5 | 2022-02-17 |
| A6 | 2022-02-17 |
| B6 | 2022-02-17 |
| C6 | 2022-02-18 |

Another is their activity_table dataframe

| ID | activity_date | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 | al23o |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 | pod5 |
| A2 | 2022-02-14 | p32olq |
| A5 | 2022-02-15 | s1df |
| B1 | 2022-02-15 | wra21s |
| A1 | 2022-02-16 | 3asDlk |
| A5 | 2022-02-17 | 12ewerf |
| A6 | 2022-02-17 | powp09 |
| A2 | 2022-02-18 | p32sdolq |
| A5 | 2022-02-18 | s1ddf |
| A1 | 2022-02-18 | wraa21s |
| C1 | 2022-02-18 | 13aslk |
| C5 | 2022-02-19 | 712werf |
| B6 | 2022-02-19 | 43pop09 |
| A2 | 2022-02-19 | 2p32olq |
| C5 | 2022-02-19 | 8s1df |
| B1 | 2022-02-20 | wraty21s |
| A6 | 2022-02-20 | 3astlk |
| B5 | 2022-02-20 | 1276werf |
| C6 | 2022-02-20 | p45op09 |

```
df_new = spark.sql("""select  * from activity_table WHERE activity_date >= '2022-02-14' AND activity_date <  '2022-02-24' AND ID in (SELECT ID FROM entry_table)""")
```

I am trying to join both the spark dataframes to have a moving sliding window with time in such a way, that IF I have a sliding window of 6 days, day1 user A1 with entry_date 2022-02-14 will only have activity data up to 2022-02-20 and the last day user in user_table C6 that's has entry_date 2022-02-18  will have activity data upto 2022-02-23

Answer (score 1):

```
//create dataset
val data = Seq(("A1","2022-02-14"), 
     ("A2","2022-02-14"), 
     ("A5","2022-02-15"), 
     ("B1","2022-02-15"), 
     ("C1","2022-02-16"), 
     ("B5","2022-02-17"), 
     ("A6","2022-02-17"), 
     ("B6","2022-02-17"), 
     ("C6","2022-02-18")).toDF("ID","entry_date")
val activity = Seq(("ID","activity_date","activity"),
("A1","2022-02-14","al23o"),
("A1","2022-02-14","pod5"),
("A2","2022-02-14","p32olq"),
("A5","2022-02-15","s1df"),
("B1","2022-02-15","wra21s"),
("A1","2022-02-16","3asDlk"),
("A5","2022-02-17","12ewerf"),
("A6","2022-02-17","powp09"),
("A2","2022-02-18","p32sdolq"),
("A5","2022-02-18","s1ddf"),
("A1","2022-02-18","wraa21s"),
("C1","2022-02-18","13aslk"),
("C5","2022-02-19","712werf"),
("B6","2022-02-19","43pop09"),
("A2","2022-02-19","2p32olq"),
("C5","2022-02-19","8s1df"),
("B1","2022-02-20","wraty21s"),
("A6","2022-02-20","3astlk"),
("B5","2022-02-20","1276werf"),
("C6","2022-02-20","p45op09")).toDF("ID","activity_date","activity")

val date_window = data
 .select( 
  col("ID"), 
  to_date(col("entry_date")).as("entry_Date") ) //make dates
 .select( 
  col("ID"),
  col("entry_Date"),
  explode ( 
   expr("sequence(entry_Date,date_add(entry_Date, 6), interval 1 day)")).as("activity_window") 
  ) //use sequence to generate dates, 
  // if you need previous six use date_sub
  // "sequence(date_sub(entry_Date, 6),entry_Date), interval 1 day)"
  //explode the sequence to generate rows from array

date_window
 .join( 
  activity, 
  date_window("activity_window") === activity("activity_date") )// join on window column
 .groupBy(
  date_window("entry_Date"),
  date_window("ID"))
 .agg( 
  arrays_zip( //zip the activity information to make one array with both data points
   collect_list("activity").as("activity"),
   collect_list("activity_date")
    .as("activity_date"))
  .as("activities_array") )
 .select( 
  col("*"),
  explode( col("activities_array")).as("activities") ) // convert array into rows
 .select( 
  col("*"),
  col("activities.*")).show() //use '.*' to pull array into columns (rename as needed)
+----------+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------+
|entry_Date| ID|    activities_array|          activities|       0|         1|
+----------+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------+
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[12ewerf, 2022-02...| 12ewerf|2022-02-17|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[powp09, 2022-02-17]|  powp09|2022-02-17|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[p32sdolq, 2022-0...|p32sdolq|2022-02-18|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...| [s1ddf, 2022-02-18]|   s1ddf|2022-02-18|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[wraa21s, 2022-02...| wraa21s|2022-02-18|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[13aslk, 2022-02-18]|  13aslk|2022-02-18|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[712werf, 2022-02...| 712werf|2022-02-19|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[43pop09, 2022-02...| 43pop09|2022-02-19|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[2p32olq, 2022-02...| 2p32olq|2022-02-19|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...| [8s1df, 2022-02-19]|   8s1df|2022-02-19|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[wraty21s, 2022-0...|wraty21s|2022-02-20|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[3astlk, 2022-02-20]|  3astlk|2022-02-20|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[1276werf, 2022-0...|1276werf|2022-02-20|
|2022-02-17| B5|[[12ewerf, 2022-0...|[p45op09, 2022-02...| p45op09|2022-02-20|
|2022-02-15| B1|[[s1df, 2022-02-1...|  [s1df, 2022-02-15]|    s1df|2022-02-15|
|2022-02-15| B1|[[s1df, 2022-02-1...|[wra21s, 2022-02-15]|  wra21s|2022-02-15|
|2022-02-15| B1|[[s1df, 2022-02-1...|[3asDlk, 2022-02-16]|  3asDlk|2022-02-16|
|2022-02-15| B1|[[s1df, 2022-02-1...|[12ewerf, 2022-02...| 12ewerf|2022-02-17|
|2022-02-15| B1|[[s1df, 2022-02-1...|[powp09, 2022-02-17]|  powp09|2022-02-17|
|2022-02-15| B1|[[s1df, 2022-02-1...|[p32sdolq, 2022-0...|p32sdolq|2022-02-18|
+----------+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: If you found my comment helpful please upvote.  If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate you marking it so when you have time.